# map to dropdown if condition is met reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to populate dropdowns only if the a certain condition is met.
I am using the *axios* `get` method for fetching data.

The code is as follows -

```
  componentDidMount = e => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(function (res) {
        let FullData = res.data;
      });
  };
```

My form is as follows-

```
   <form>
    <select>address</select>
    <option id={FullData.zipcode}>{FullData.street}</option>
  </form>
```

I need this to work only if the `{ FullData.city }` is "Gwenborough".
Please refer [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) for the JSON.

Comment: You can't do conditions like 'if' in react body like this <option>{if ...}</option> that's going to be an error. So the I think is best to use a function and do your testing in it for example

Comment: So there should be no dropdown when the city is not the Gwenborough?Can you maybe post the full code?

Comment: @Gh05d Yes it should be empty if city is not Gwensborough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. You generally need to put your values in state, so whenever they are received in asynchronous way, the component gets updated.

Here's a [Demo sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-74rpn)

```
class DropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      FullData: [],
    }
  }
  componentDidMount=(e)=>{
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              FullData: res
            }) 
        })
  }

  render() {
    let { FullData } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
          <label>Address </label>
          <select>
            {FullData
              .filter(user => user.address.city === "Gwenborough")
              .map(user => {
              return <option key={user.id} id={user.zipcode}>{user.address.street}</option>
            })}

          </select>
       
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Note I was using `fetch` instead of `axios`.
Another note - I really like Dexter's answer and the way the action is put into separate function. It looks like a better approach to structuring your code in general. It probably wouldn't work as it is only because of how your data is structured: you get and array of users and you only have `city` and `street` inside the `address` key. Cheers!

Comment: Why use fetch rather than axios? Wont it work similarly?

Comment: @Preeti sure, but I just copied it from the Demo sandbox I used, it was more convenient to me, but makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry to bother but I am using Material UI for Select and MenuItem(for option) and when I'm selecting an option its not shown. Do you know why?

Comment: Not sure why, without looking at some code. Make sure to provide the ‘value’ property to MenuItem, i.e. “value={user.address.street}” or whatever data you need as selection.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help. Note your question isn't clear enough to provide working examples to help me understand the full scope of what you're talking about, so this is my best guess on the solution to your question.

```
constructor(){
          this.selection=null;
          this.doSomeTesting=this.doSomeTesting.bind(this);
        }
        doSomeTesting(FullData){
           if(FullData.city ===  "Gwenborough"){   
              return (<option id={FullData.zipcode}>{FullData.street}</option>);
           }
           return ""; //return nothing useful if not what you're looking for
        }
         componentDidMount=(e)=>{
            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .then(function(res){
                    let FullData=res.data
                    this.selection = this.doSomeTesting(FullData);
                })
          }
    
        render(){
            <form>
            <select>address</select>
              {this.selection}
             </form>
         }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying doSomething is not defined. Can you share the code in Codebox or any other platform?